# Transform multiple strings in integers

Tags: python, string, for-loop, integer

I am trying to transform into integers two strings (that are numbers) separated by a space, but I keep failing. I have tried numerous different solution, but nothing seems to work.

```
f= open('new.txt', 'r')
list_author = []


for line in f:
    header1 = f.readline()
    header2 = f.readline()
    header3 = f.readline()
    line = line.strip().replace('\t', ' ')
    line=list(map(str,line.split()))
    list_author.append([line])

print(list_author[1:10])
```

Output (formatted for readability):

```
[[['#', 'Directed', 'graph', '(each', 'unordered', 'pair', 'of', 'nodes', 'is', 'saved']],
 [['3466', '937']],
 [['3466', '15931']],
 [['10310', '1854']],
 [['10310', '9572']],
 [['10310', '16310']],
 [['10310', '24814']],
 [['5052', '3096']],
 [['5052', '5740']],
 [['5052', '10235']]]
```

Comment: Please update the question with 1) a sample from the input file, and 2) the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first line is a header so you need to skip it. Then, you can use `numbers = line.split("\t")` on every line to have both numbers. Then you can add them into a the author´s list like this: `list_author.append((int(number[0]),int(number[1])))`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `str` to `int` using `int("123")` but i would be careful, your code will bomb out if you try to parse anything except an `int`, `str` or `float` and it must be a valid number, so you need to catch both `TypeError` and `ValueError`. I would wrap it in a function that you can call for each iteration:

```
def coerce(value: str) -> int or None:
    try:
        return int(value)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        # this is not convertible
        return None
```